# Has anyone made slick grid work properly with 1 stylesheet?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9, stylesheet, slickgrid

I am running into an 'IE9 and lower' bug of SlickGrid where the page is hitting the limit of 31 stylesheets.  I have seen several posts containing 'fixes' for this issue, but they do not actually fix the problem, and they usually fix styles for the last-rendered grid only.

The best description for this issue is outlined here, and I am in a similar situation to the last commenter on the thread, in that I need several grids at once, but only have 3 or 4 stylesheets available(within the IE9 limit).
https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/issues/213

I am using slickGrid version: v2.1, and appreciate any/all suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into some problems with IE9 recently, too.  Is this MVC?  If so, it is my understanding that there is a max bundle size of 250k.  I just broke up the bundles to < 250k and it worked.
As here: [Stylesheets not loading in IE 9 despite mime type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23361421/stylesheets-not-loading-in-ie-9-despite-mime-type/23366721?noredirect=1#comment35819491_23366721)