# Stylesheets not loading in IE 9 despite mime type

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer-9, stylesheet

I have an MVC 4 application making use of bundling and minification. The application works 100% correct on IE 11, chrome and other browsers but the style sheets are not rendering when using IE9.

I added the following to my web.config's system.webserver section

```
<staticContent>
  <remove fileExtension=".css"/>
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".css" mimeType="text/css"/>
</staticContent>
```

and it seems that the mime type is correct when using IE's developer tools

[image]

If the mime type is correct and all stylesheets seems to load, why won't it render?

**Side Note:** I'm also using Twitter Bootstrap 3 and FontAwesome, not sure if this is causing problems.

**UPDATE:**

When I use fiddler I can see that the mime type is still set to text/css; charset=utf-8

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ok, eventually found the problem. This was not a problem with the mime type and I hope this will save someone a few hours. IE9 limits the size of css files to about 250kb, because I'm using bundling and minification one of my css bundles were exceeding this limit and the file was truncated, resulting in some of the styles not being applied.

The fix was rather easy, I split my css bundle into two bundles, for example

```
 bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Bundles/Shared/CSS").Include(
            "~/Content/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css",
            "~/Content/font-awesome.min.css",
            "~/Content/silviomoreto-bootstrap-select/bootstrap-select.min.css",
            "~/Content/kendo/kendo.common.min.css"));

  bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Bundles/SharedTwo/CSS").Include(
            "~/Content/datepicker/css/datepicker.css",
            "~/Content/kendo/kendo.bootstrap.min.css",
            "~/Content/bootstrap-touchspin-master/libraries/prettify/prettify.css",
            "~/Content/bootstrap-touchspin-master/libraries/prettify/demo.css",
            "~/Content/css/Shared/Index.css"));
```

Comment: Thanks, this saved me a lot of frustration.  I guess here on out, I won't load files into a bundle using wildcards.  Did you have any problem with sprites loading as well?

Comment: Had no problem with sprites.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I figured it out...it was a different problem with relative/absolute paths.  I switched up to using Url.Content().

Comment: Thanks for this.  I had the exact same problem using Telerik Kendo UI on IE9 because I was bundling the Kendo CSS files into a single bundle.  It was exceeding the 250kb size and dropping styles.  I split it into two bundles and that solved the problem.

Comment: @John81 Glad it saved you some time, took me a while to figure out.

Comment: I imagine it did.  It drove me nuts for about an hour before I found this post!

Comment: Wow, glad I found this, saved me hours as well! Such an obscure issue.