# Foundation 5 Internet Explorer 9

Tags: wordpress, internet-explorer-9, zurb-foundation

It would seem that the Foundation 5 WordPress site I am working on does not work in IE9.

I expected this structurally, however the stylesheet does not appear to be loading AT ALL.

Are there any standard ways to fix IE9 and Foundation or is it a long and laborious, manual process?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the mime type your CSS is being served with.  If it's not `text/css`, IE9 will ignore it.  Mine was being served as `text/css; charset=utf-8`, and it didn't work.  Once I changed it, it worked as expected.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. I had no luck with this. Is there any other common fixes I could try?

Comment: Not sure; what I mentioned worked for me.  I assume you've searched on here?  [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23361421/stylesheets-not-loading-in-ie-9-despite-mime-type) says there's a size restriction on CSS files - is yours > 250kb?  Just to troubleshoot, does it work in Compatibility View (see [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/03/27/http-406-not-acceptable-php-ie9-standards-mode-accepts-only-text_2f00_css-for-stylesheets.aspx))?

Answer (score 0):

We ran into the same issue using Foundation outside of WordPress.  The culprit was our app.css file - which was 241K minified.

We split the Foundation components into a separate CSS file (with our fonts and a couple of other global features), foundation.min.css is about 209K.

That left about 35K in style style overrides in app.min.css.

That fixed the problem for the 3% of our users who use IE9. :^P